# sending a response to another php file using $curl returns an error

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to send JSON data to another php file for now for learning purpose (actually meant to be sent to a react-native app) but this returns an error saying

> Error: call to URL http://localhost/hhh.php failed with status 200, response , curl_error , curl_errno 0

```
 if($cliSeq==0)
    {
        $welcomearr= array("welcome");
              $url = "http://localhost/hhh.php";   

            $welcomeJSON = json_encode($welcomearr);


             $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-type: application/json"));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $welcomeJSON);

            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            if ( $status != 201 ) {
                die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
            }


            curl_close($curl);

            $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
}
```

Comment: Because it response with http status 200 but you failed it because it is not 201. No curl error because the request went through and server responded with 200

Comment: Status 200 means "ok", if the response is empty, you need to check the php portion receiving the request to figure out why it's not generating any output.